# How to make this empty space between link text and :after clickable?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emils/1wbbgsm8/).

If you hover mouse between the "CLOSE" and the :after element which is a triangle then you can't click the link.

Is there a way to make that area clickable and still make it look the same?

HTML:

```
<div class="close">
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.close {
    margin-top: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.close > a {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.close > a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 4px;
    right: -32px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: an easy way around would be to do this -within the `<a>` you can use a `font-awesome icon` to make it look same and will be clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` and `padding-right: 30px` to `a` tag, change `right: 0px` for `:after`

Comment: Thanks, also had to change `top: 4px` to `top: 2px` for :after, because of `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/n0hs9q14/

```
.close {
    margin-top: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.close > a {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block; /* if vertical padding is required */
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}
.close > a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 13px;
    right: 0;
    /*right: -32px; dont take arrow out of parent */
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

what i have done is bring arrow inside the `a` tag by giving `a` some padding on right and giving `right:0` to `:after`.. and background is just for visibility and `top` of `:after` was changed to align it vertically